# How to match a specific column position till the end of line?

Tags: regular-expression

`^` denote the beginning of the line ,`$` denote the end of the line.
Suppose that there is a line in my vim:

```
this is a test line test line.
```

I want to remove all the characters from the 20 th character in the current line (line number is 1) till the end of line.

```
1s/20th,$//
```

How to express the 20th character in line1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See `:h \%c`:

```
                        */\%c* */\%>c* */\%<c*
\%23c   Matches in a specific column.
\%<23c  Matches before a specific column.
\%>23c  Matches after a specific column.
\%.c    Matches at the cursor column.
\%<.c   Matches before the cursor column.
\%>.c   Matches after the cursor column.
```

In your case:

```
:s/\%20c.*//
```